# Aforge.NET - Get items from StringBuilder

Tags: c#, image-processing, blob, aforge, getpixel

I'm creating a program that is designed to check multiple choice tests. My application is meant squares which will search the pixels of a different color than the background color (white). Stringbuilder I used to line up the position of individual points (square corners).

My question is: How the StringBuilder, which you can see in the codeblock below,
first assign a value to a variable myPoint.X a second (separated by commas) to the variable myPoint.Y? In stringbuilder I separate the points by a semicolon?

Secondly: Is having these points I can draw squares, between which I will search the pixels?

Thanks for help.

```
public void ImageProcessing(PictureBox pbox, Bitmap bitmap, TextBox tb1)
        {
            //var nbitmap = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage(bitmap);
            bitmap = (Bitmap)pbox.Image.Clone();
            BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width,
                bitmap.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
            ColorFiltering colorFiltering = new ColorFiltering();

            colorFiltering.Red = new IntRange(0, 64);
            colorFiltering.Green = new IntRange(0, 64);
            colorFiltering.Blue = new IntRange(0, 64);
            colorFiltering.FillOutsideRange = false;
            colorFiltering.ApplyInPlace(bitmapData);

            IntPoint myPoint = new IntPoint();

            BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
            blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
            blobCounter.MinHeight = 15;
            blobCounter.MinWidth = 15;

            blobCounter.ProcessImage(bitmapData);
            Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

            SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();


            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
            Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3);
            List<IntPoint> corners = new List<IntPoint>();


            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string stg = "";


            List<IntPoint> zbior = new List<IntPoint>();

            for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
            {
                List<IntPoint> edgePoints =     blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);

                if (shapeChecker.IsQuadrilateral(edgePoints, out corners))
                {

                    PolygonSubType subType = shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(corners);

                    Pen pen = null;

                    if (subType == PolygonSubType.Square)
                    {

                        pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? redPen : bluePen;
                        foreach (var item in corners)
                        {
                            sb.Append(item).Append(";");

                        }

                    }


                    g.DrawPolygon(pen, ToPointsArray(corners));
                }

            }
tb1.Text = stg;

                redPen.Dispose();
                bluePen.Dispose();
                g.Dispose();
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(bitmap);
                pbox.Image = bitmap;
            }

        }
```

Comment: OK. Now i have Array of points. The question is: How i can search the bitmap(limited by the points of the corners of my squares) for different color than color of my background? Is it possible to mark this squares where are another color?

Answer (score 0):

You return the string from a StringBuilder by calling the ToString() method on it, which will return the entire string.

I'm not sure want your second question is though, could you please elaborate?